# How to get data from an Facebook apprequest response?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to figure out how I can get data from an apprequest response:

```
function invite(provider) {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'Check this thing out!',
        title: 'Request Title'
    }, function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            console.log('3 friend invited.');
            console.log(response);
        } else {
            console.log('You have to invite 2 friends.');
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

`console.log(response);` returns:

```
Object {
    request: "667131760069164",
    to: Array[1]
}
request: "667131760069164"
to: Array[1] 0: "1476807679266627"
length: 1
```

I'm wondering how I can get the information stored in `to:` to check how many were invited.

Thoughts, anyone?

Comment: Try to find value in Obj.to[0] or Obj.to['0'] .. May be it will help

Comment: Can you give an example @reenleedr?

Comment: I am sorry .. very sorry. But correct Answer is OBJ.to[0][0]

Comment: and here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jq4mp4xc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the result I wanted with:

```
if (response.to.length > 2) {
    console.log('Success! You have invited ' + response.to.length + ' friends.');
} else {
    console.log('You need to invite at least 3 friends')
}
```

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
obj = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(obj.to[0][0]);
console.log(obj.to[0].length);
```

You can access first value in 'to' array by **obj.to[0][0]** and **obj.to[0].length**